# What is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $Q^T \Lambda Q$ and $\Lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, orthonormal

Suppose $N\geq p$. Let $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times p}$ has orthonormal columns $q_1,\dots,q_p$. Let $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ be a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1 \geq \dots \geq \lambda_N \geq 0$.

What I am interested in is how to use the eigenvalues or singular values of $Q$ and $\Lambda$ to bound the eigenvalues of $Q^T \Lambda Q \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$, especially the largest eigenvalue of $Q^T \Lambda Q$.

Comment: Are $Q$ and $\Lambda$ obtained from diagonalizing some square matrix $A$?

Comment: No, $Q$ and $\Lambda$ are not related. They are arbitrarily selected. We just require $Q$ has orthonormal columns and $\Lambda$ has non-negative descending diagonal entries.

Comment: @Z The non-zero eigenvalues of $Q^T\Lambda Q$ must be equal to the non-zero eigenvalues of $\Lambda QQ^T$. The [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) gives a relationship between the eigenvalues of $Q^T\Lambda Q$ and those of $\Lambda$, but these have no connection to the eigenvalues of $Q^TQ$. Note that because the columns of $Q$ are orthonormal, we have $Q^TQ = I$, which means that all of its eigenvalues are equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ represent the linear function induced by your diagonal matrix, it has operator norm $\lambda_1$. You may think of $Q^T \Lambda Q$ as $i\circ w\circ f\circ q$ where $w$ is a projection, $i$ an isometric isomorphism (from the image of $w$ to some $p$-dimensional space) and $q$ is an isometry. Hence you may bound the eigenvalues of $Q^T \Lambda Q$ by $\lambda_1$. Also all the eigenvalues of the new matrix are non negative if you need a lower bound.